# Problem with a warn command discord.py KeyError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm having some problems with a warn command I believe the problem is a KeyError but I don't know how to fix it. Here is the code. I did review the code but I can't find why the error is happening. Thank you for all the help you can give and I hope this code isn't to bad to review lol.

```
async def warncount():
    with open("warncount.json", 'r') as f:
        count = json.load(f)
    number = count[str("Number")]
    return number

async def get_warn_data():
    with open("warns.json", 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)
    return warns


@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, arg="No reason given"):
    number = await warncount()
    warns = await get_warn_data()
    case = number+1
    if str(member.id) in warns:
        try:
            obj = {"Author": ctx.author, "Reason": arg}
            warns[str(member.id)][case].append(obj)
            with open("warns.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(warns, f)
        except:
            try:
                obj = {"Author": ctx.author, "Reason": arg}
                warns[str(member.id)][case] = obj
                with open("warns.json", 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(warns, f)
            except Exception:
                print(Exception)
        with open("warncount.json", 'r') as f:
            count = json.load(f)
        count[str("Number")] += 1
        with open("warncount.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(count, f)
        await ctx.send(f"{member} has been warned for {arg} to check his warns do .warns {member}")

    else:
        try:
            warns[str(member.id)]
            with open("warns.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(warns, f)
        except Exception:
            print(Exception)
        try:
            obj = {"Author": ctx.author, "Reason": arg}
            warns[str(member.id)][case].append(obj)
            with open("warns.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(warns, f)
        except:
            try:
                obj = {"Author": ctx.author, "Reason": arg}
                warns[str(member.id)][case] = obj
                with open("warns.json", 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(warns, f)
            except Exception:
                print(Exception)
        with open("warncount.json", 'r') as f:
            count = json.load(f)
        count[str("Number")] += 1
        with open("warncount.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(count, f)
        await ctx.send(f"{member} has been warned for {arg} to check his warns do .warns {member}")
```

Comment: *"No error"* is really not helpful, then please debug the code.

Comment: "No error" doesn't matter here. This library have many logical errors and thus the interpreter doesn't show it. We have to debug it ourselves in this case.

Comment: We don't exactly know what you are trying to do, and what is supposed to happen. Try [print debugging](https://www.google.com/search?q=print+debugging+python&newwindow=1&ei=j25-YMXFMZ6I4-EPgu6UwA0&oq=print+debugging+python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAOgcIABBHELADOgYIABAWEB5QhDRYojtgijxoAXACeACAAf0CiAG6B5IBBzQuMi4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiFyaeUk4zwAhUexDgGHQI3BdgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) and try to find out where you are going wrong.

Comment: Ill do it let me just print it

Comment: Ok so error is a KeyError on the line 
```
try:
            warns[str(member.id)]
            with open("warns.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(warns, f)
```
error on warns[str(member.id)]

Error: KeyError: 'member's id'